# Using own Bootstrap 3 files

Tags: 7, theming, cdn

I would like to know how I can host my own Bootstrap 3 files (js, css) in the Drupal 7 Bootstrap 3 theme. I know I can deactivate CDN hosting inside the theme settings, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone of you guide me through?

Comment: Please check the following link it list step by step bootstrap integration with d7.
[enter link description here](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-use-bootswatch-themes-drupal-7)

Answer (score 2):

I've had success utilizing the [Bootstrap Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library) module.

> This module loads via libraries the Bootstrap files installed on /sites/all/libraries/bootstrap, regardless of the theme you are using. It does nothing else.
>
> When using Bootstrap themes is particularly helpful to:
>
> 1. Correct Browser Support issues, installing respond.js.
> 2. Update your Bootstrap version over your current theme options.
> 3. Just to avoid CDN files loading.