# Bootstrap load theme locally

Tags: 7, bootstrap-theme

How do I load the Bootstrap theme (css, js, fonts) locally?

I've searched around the drupal stack exchange, but every suggestion I've come across doesn't solve the problem. It seems like the other option is to create a sub-theme, but I'm not even sure if that will load all the necessary files for bootstrap locally/offline. The whole purpose of this is to load the bootstrap theme and its css/js/fonts without using any internet.

The issue is that I'm seeing the error as another user did like this:
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/screenshot_218.jpg

There are answers like these below, but there has to be a way to do it without more installation other than drupal modules:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010
[Using own Bootstrap 3 files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/using-own-bootstrap-3-files)

Comment: I wrote a short article on how to do this clearly...for 2018 also: http://brunovincent.net/data/how-to-install-use-drupal-7-bootstrap-theme-locally-without-cdn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download bootstrap package and include it in your theme folder.

and go to `admin/appearance/settings/bootstrap`
then go to 'Advanced' and change CDN provider to `custom`.
give your local bootstrap css,js urls.

if you need to import it to a custom theme you can add it the bootstrap package like below.

your_theme.info

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/bootstrap.css
scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js
```

define the regions you need in your custom theme info file.

remmber to use the 'https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update' module for JS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your method and it worked.

As a side note, for anyone that doesn't know the local bootstrap URLs (like me), the URL is: 
[https://yoursitename.com/sites/all/libraries/bootstrap/]

Comment: Great! glad it helped :)

Comment: "You can download bootstrap package and include it in your theme folder." 
 --- Package has a zillion files...what folder exactly to paste?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple . Please follow these step to create a sub theme using bootstrap.

1. Install drupal bootstrap theme.
2. copy less folder from starterkits.
3. Download bootstrap css and js file in your sub theme folder.
4. configure you theme info file.

   ```
    stylesheets[all][] = css/bootstrap.css
    scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js
   ```
5. Enable your sub theme.

If you have any problem I create a video tutorial for you please click on this link [tutorial](http://youtu.be/Z6QfHP35gG0?hd=1)

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the solution by danuddara, but I'm going to try your solution in another instance of drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future - if you have no option to compile less files (as me) you can:

> 0) Install bootstrap base theme
>
> 1) Copy less folder from starterkits to `/themes` folder and rename it
>   as you want
>
> 2) Download bootstrap css and js file in your sub theme folder into
>   `/bootstrap`
>
> 3) NEW: copy css file from base theme (from folder
>   `/css/YOUR_BT_VERSION` ) - this is the compiled css - it is nesesary
>   for many drupal features. I add this file in /css folder and rename it
>   to `overrides.css`
>
> 4) Configure you theme info file as usual (change name as folder
>   name), add description...
>
> 5) Add `stylesheets[all][] = bootstrap/bootstrap.css` line and one
>   more line for file from step 4 in your theme.info file -
>   `stylesheets[all][] = css/overrides.css`